# Cancel mousedown event (with plain js) on anchor element wrapped in <li>

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
 <li id="aCont">
  <a href="http://test.com">test</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("aCont").onmousedown= function (e) {
 //some Action
}
<script>
```

I didn't manage to make it with `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` neither with `return false`. Is it possible to be canceled this event at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your intention is to stop the click on the anchor element from navigating to the specified URL then you need to be using the "onclick" event, not "onmousedown".

With an old-school `element.onsomeevent =` handler only non-IE browsers pass the event object to the function as a parameter, while IE has a `window.event` property - so you need to allow for that too.

And, again, IE does things differently when preventing the default action associated with events: for IE set the event's `returnValue` property to false, for non-IE call `e.preventDefault()` (note the "t" on the end of "prevent" - you've spelled it wrong in your question) and/or return false from the handler.

Combining all of that:

```
document.getElementById("aCont").onclick = function(e) {
   // allow for IE, which doesn't pass the event object as a parameter
   if (!e) e = window.event;

   e.returnValue = false;
   if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();

   return false;
}
```

(Note: you've also spelled `e.stopPropagation()` wrong, but you don't need that method for this purpose - it stops the event bubbling up to parent elements, it doesn't cancel the default action.)

Comment: The bad thing is that I'm not allowed to change the event type.

Comment: Well you could copy the contents of my function and keep the `onmousedown` event and see what happens. At least then you'll be dealing with the way different browsers cancel events. I've never tried to cancel hyperlink navigation from `onmousedown` because certainly `onclick` is the _correct_ place to do it, but maybe it'll work - you only get a click event after a mouse down and up, so... (And my apologies: I just noticed that I left the actual word `.onclick` out of my code so I've just now edited it in.)

Comment: P.S. I should've mentioned that even if you get it to work with a mousedown, note that the link will still work if the user activates it from the keyboard. A click event, on the other hand, will be triggered by mouse click or keyboard "click".