# Strange behavior with openlink with middle mouse combined with alert

Tags: javascript

So I posted a answer to this question [Disable mouse scroll middle click event with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316004/disable-mouse-scroll-middle-click-event-with-jquery/60316139#60316139)
And came up with this solution. I know how to solve this problem, but I just cant understand why this behavior is happening

```js
document.onmousedown= function (e) {
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("middle button pressed, dont open"); 
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"> click here </a>
```

After some time a got a comment saying it doesn't work when removing the `alert()`, so i tested it and he was right. Now the tab is opened on middle mouse click

```js
document.onmousedown= function (e) {
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#dontwanttoopen"> click here </a>
```

What is causing this behavior? First i thought it was a chrome feature/bug but it's the same behavior with edge and IE

Comment: Snippets can't open windows anyway, but I can verify the behavior: [With `alert`](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/mgn2rho8/), [without `alert`](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/mgn2rho8/1/).

Comment: Try `return false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel mousedown event (with plain js) on anchor element wrapped in <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094245/cancel-mousedown-event-with-plain-js-on-anchor-element-wrapped-in-li)

Comment: @Justinas - `return false` from a DOM0 handler is just the same thing as `e.preventDefault()` (and this issue happens on Chrome for me). More on my blog: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html

Comment: @Justinas I know how to solve it, but i just cant understand why this behavior is happening

Comment: For me, the `click` event doesn't even fire when I'm doing a middle click (`mousedown` does). Huh.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hhm interesting, what os/browser are you using? I can even open a new tab in the snippet

Comment: @PEPEGA - Linux Mint. And you're right, I also get a window opening, even from the snippet. Which is odd, I thought they weren't allowed to do that...